# Update A* to Jump Point Search

Tags: c#, path-finding, a-star

I have tried to integrate a JPS in my A* algorithm, but the performance is dropped. Reading the documentation and samples in GitHub, currently confused why is works slow. What should be corrected while checking or adding to some lists? Maybe I didn't understand the full sense of this algorithm.

Here is my function which is modified Astar:

```
public List<PathFinderNode> FindPath(Point start, Point end, List<Point> ResultPoints)
{
    PathFinderNode parentNode;
    bool found = false;
    int gridX = mGrid[0].Count - 1;//horizontal size of grid
    int gridY = mGrid.Count - 1; //vertical size of grid
    mStopped = false;
    mOpen.Clear();
    mClose.Clear();
    parentNode.G = 0;
    parentNode.H = mHEstimate; //Equals 2
    parentNode.F = parentNode.G + parentNode.H;
    parentNode.X = start.X;
    parentNode.Y = start.Y;
    parentNode.PX = parentNode.X;
    parentNode.PY = parentNode.Y;
    mOpen.Push(parentNode); //Add a ParentNode First
    while (mOpen.Count > 0)
    {
        parentNode = mOpen.Pop();
        if (parentNode.X == end.X && parentNode.Y == end.Y)
        {
            mClose.Add(parentNode);
            found = true;
            break;
        }

        if (mClose.Count > mSearchLimit)
        {
            mStopped = true;
            return null;
        }

        //Checking Neibours
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            PathFinderNode newNode;
            newNode.X = parentNode.X + direction[i, 0];
            newNode.Y = parentNode.Y + direction[i, 1];

            var tmpXY = jump(newNode.X, newNode.Y, parentNode.X, parentNode.Y, start,end); //doing a jump action

            if (tmpXY[0] != -1) //if jump returns more than -1
            {
                int newG;
                newNode.X = tmpXY[0];
                newNode.Y = tmpXY[1];

                newG = parentNode.G + (-1) * mGrid[newNode.Y][newNode.X];
                if (newG == parentNode.G)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                int foundInOpenIndex = -1;
                for (int j = 0; j < mOpen.Count; j++) //openList check
                {
                    if (mOpen[j].X == newNode.X && mOpen[j].Y == newNode.Y)
                    {
                        foundInOpenIndex = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (foundInOpenIndex != -1 && mOpen[foundInOpenIndex].G <= newG)
                    continue;

                int foundInCloseIndex = -1;

                for (int j = 0; j < mClose.Count; j++) //ClosedListCheck
                {
                    if (mClose[j].X == newNode.X && mClose[j].Y == newNode.Y)
                    {
                        foundInCloseIndex = j;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (foundInCloseIndex != -1 && mClose[foundInCloseIndex].G <= newG)
                    continue;

                newNode.PX = parentNode.X;
                newNode.PY = parentNode.Y;
                newNode.G = newG;
                newNode.H = mHEstimate * (Math.Abs(newNode.X - end.X) + Math.Abs(newNode.Y - end.Y)); //Manhattan
                newNode.F = newNode.G + newNode.H;
                mOpen.Push(newNode);
            }
        }
        mClose.Add(parentNode);
    }
    if (found)
    {
        PathFinderNode fNode = mClose[mClose.Count - 1];
        for (int i = mClose.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (fNode.PX == mClose[i].X && fNode.PY == mClose[i].Y || i == mClose.Count - 1)
            {
                fNode = mClose[i];
                ResultPoints.Add(new Point(fNode.X * 10, fNode.Y * 10));
            }
            else
                mClose.RemoveAt(i);

        }
        mStopped = true;
        return mClose;
    }
    mStopped = true;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Have you collected any benchmarks? What part is slow?

Comment: Yes, the slowest part after run jump searching in sample code, before integrating JPS the perfomance from one point to other in map[100x100] took 0.100 s, after it takes approximately a second

Comment: You could use a collection type that's more suited to frequent removal of items such as `LinkedList<>`.

Comment: @itsme86 I use this solution for removal items https://github.com/BlueRaja/High-Speed-Priority-Queue-for-C-Sharp/tree/master/Priority%20Queue%20Example it works fast

Comment: Yes, it would be. :)

Comment: You should tell us where you have identified problems. The idea is show what research you have done so people don't repeat work for no reason.

Comment: @jdv I found a problem with differences while checking close and open lists after JPS ran. Is the list check the same as in astar, or not? Thx a lot

Comment: What does your graph look like?  JPS is only faster in 2D grids with large open areas; if it's something like a maze, JPS won't provide any benefit.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft My map is 2d array size of [108;192] have a marked by special number bounds, with the marked rectangles, that is it. The matrix is big, this algorithm should work really fast. I checked a demo in Github)